# Endless Runner in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project where I have to create an endless runner game in unity. The problem I have is in the collision aspect of the game where the sphere and one of the objects collide I want the sphere to be destroyed. This is the code I have for it:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "lethal")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }                      
}
```

I tagged the objects within the game as `lethal`. The problem is even with this code the sphere, when colliding, is not destroyed rather its just an obstacle that stops the ball rather than destroying it.

Any help? not sure what i am doing wrong

Comment: About the second part and obstacle, is your collider a trigger?

Comment: maybe `Destroy(other.gameObject);`?

Comment: Not sure if it will have any effect on your problem but just a little comment. You shouldn't use == to compare string types instead use: other.gameObject.tag.equals("lethal")

Comment: @Niklas7 Actually in C#, they work the same. In Java they work diffrently :)

Comment: @Nirasiu oh damn Java was my primary language so I kinda just went with that theorie haha. But thanks now I know

Comment: You should use CompareTag(), it's much much more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Disable the physics between them. If your game lags and destruction takes place slow, your "runner" will be disturbed by this
- Instead of collider use ontriggerentered
- Do not use string comparisons with "==" instead use equals or CompareTag as @Jichael suggested.

And if you really want to use physics, make a child object to your runner and that should trigger the collision instead of your runner. And give the tag to that child object